# why does selection sort method start loop with "i = from + 1"

Tags: java, sorting, selection

i am working with a selection short method to sort an array. the method starts its minimumPosition method with a for loop that starts with "i = from + 1". why does it start with that instead of "i = 0"?

can someone explain this for me please?

thanks!

edit: added context

```
/**
 Finds the smallest element in a tail range of the array.
 @param a the array to sort
@param from the first position in a to compare
@return the position of the smallest element in the
 range a[from] . . . a[a.length - 1]
*/
private static int minimumPosition(int[] a, int from)
 {
int minPos = from;
for (int i = from + 1; i < a.length; i++)
{
if (a[i] < a[minPos]) { minPos = i; }
}
 return minPos;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code so we have some context for this question?

Comment: You working on it. Tell us why you wrote `i = from + 1`

Comment: Because you are trying to find minimum and you don't need to compare a[from] to itself. Basically it is a small optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ocumentation already tells you why its `i = from +1` and not `i = 0`. Documentation: `Finds the smallest element in a tail range of the array.`

Since the method finds the smallest element tailing `from` the loop only compares every element at the position `from` or greater. And since `a[from]` is the initial minimum you can start comparing at position `from+1`.